# When the browser is closed, is saved data in session lost?

Tags: php, session

In PHP,  I create a session and add data to it. Then we close the browser. When I reopen the browser, can I still get that data from the session ?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a user's session persist after they close the browser, please review:

> session.cookie_lifetime specifies the lifetime of the cookie in seconds which is sent to the browser. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed." Defaults to 0. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

Shown at the [Runtime Configuration page regarding sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime). This way, rather than the session cookie only lasting until the browser is closed, it can persist and continue on when they re-open the browser and go back to your site.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on session's cookie parameters (if you are using built-in sessions). If `expires` set `0`, session will expire when browser is closed.
See [`setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) for details